# How do I set select default option in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I have json data that is retrieved from the server that looks like this:

```
$scope.StateList = {"States": [
    {
        "Id": 1,
        "Code": "AL",
        "Name": "Alabama"
    },
    {
        "Id": 2,
        "Code": "AK",
        "Name": "Alaska"
    },
    {
        "Id": 3,
        "Code": "AZ",
        "Name": "Arizona"
    },
    {
        "Id": 4,
        "Code": "AR",
        "Name": "Arkansas"
    }]}

$scope.Address = {"Address": {
    "Address1": "123 Maple" ,
    "Address2": null,
    "City": "Tempe",
    "State": "AZ",
    "ZipCode": null,
    "Country": null,
    "Id": 0,
    "Latitude": 0,
    "Longitude": 0
}}
```

I set up a select that looks like the following:

```
  <select ng-model="Address.State">
    <option ng-repeat="template in StateList.States">{{template.Code}}</option>
  </select>
```

I need to be able to get the Address.State field to be bound to the value selected, be the initial value of the select options. I have not be able to nail this one down and would be grateful for anyone who can show me what I am missing. [Here is a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/SkODzf2BckbmVngwK8KJ) for a live version to work with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is to use [ng-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select) directive and an ngModel and let angular create the options for you. Try this way:-

```
 <select ng-model="Address.Address.State" 
         ng-options="state.Code as state.Name for state in StateList.States"></select>
```

**[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/yx6v5l2VoeO3z300Whh4?p=preview)**

Basically this uses the syntax

> "select" as "label" for "value" in "array"

Answer (score 0):

you can either use ng-options as suggested by PSL or you can use value attribute of options

```
<option ng-repeat="template in StateList.States" 
       value="{{template.Code}}">{{template.Code}}</option>
```

[PLUNKER LINK](http://plnkr.co/edit/GvVABtgy58Nv4DDb4sY6?p=preview)

Comment: The only problem with that example is the initial value isn't set in the select, thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

It is preferred to use the `ng-options` binding provided specifically for select dropdowns instead of `ng-repeat` which provides for iteration. The below markup will provide the default text and the dropdown options

```
<select ng-model='Address.State' ng-options="template.Code for template in StateList.States" >
    <option value=""> Select one </option>
</select>
```